# How to put an API Return into different variables

Tags: php, arrays, curl

I'm using an API to display information from my visitors and going to store some of the details in a database from when the signup to the site. The response I get from the API is like this:

> {"data":{"ua_type":"Desktop","os_name":"Windows","os_version":"10","browser_name":"Firefox","browser_version":"52.0","engine_name":"Gecko","engine_version":"20100101"}}

How do I go about doing it so that I can place some of the values into a variable; so for example:

```
$device = ua_type;

$os = os_name;

etc....
```

Any help would be great please.

## Update

I've had a look at `json_decode` like a few of you have mentioned and below is some of my code, it wont display any of the values for some reason, whats wrong with my code below? The `print_r($result);` works fine but placing the results in variables doesn't seem to output anything.

```
$result = curl_exec($ch);
    $http = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);
    
    print_r($result);
    $apiresult = json_decode($result);

$ua_type=$apiresult->{'ua_type'};
$os_name=$apiresult->{'os_name'};
$os_version=$apiresult->{'os_version'};
$browser_name=$apiresult->{'browser_name'};
$browser_version=$apiresult->{'browser_version'};
$ua_brand=$apiresult->{'ua_brand'};
$ua_name=$apiresult->{'ua_name'};

echo "<br>";
echo "Device" . $ua_type;
echo "<br>";
echo "OS" . $os_name;
echo "<br>";
echo "OS Version" . $os_version;
echo "<br>";
echo "Browser" . $browser_name;
echo "<br>";
echo "Browser Version" . $browser_version;
echo "<br>";
echo "Mobile Make" . $ua_brand;
echo "<br>";
echo "Mobile Model" . $ua_name;
```

Comment: [json_decode($api_response);](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: Read up on `json_decode`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: Hi, I've placed an update on the topic, i cant get my code to work for some reason, please can i get you to take a look at it for me. Thank you for the help so far guys!

Answer (score 0):

As some comments on your post have suggested, you should read up on [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) as it'll do exactly what you're looking for :)

```
$data = json_decode('{"data":{"ua_type":"Desktop","os_name":"Windows","os_version":"10","browser_name":"Firefox","browser_version":"52.0","engine_name":"Gecko","engine_version":"20100101"}}', true);
```

Will result in the following datastructure:

```
[
     "data" => [
       "ua_type" => "Desktop",
       "os_name" => "Windows",
       "os_version" => "10",
       "browser_name" => "Firefox",
       "browser_version" => "52.0",
       "engine_name" => "Gecko",
       "engine_version" => "20100101",
     ],
   ]
```

Then, you can simply assign variables to whichever bit you need, like so:

`$ua_type = $data['data']['ua_type']`

Comment: Instead of assigning variables one by one, you should use the [`extract`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) function.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte *Should* is a subjective here. While you certainly can extract, for code readability here I probably wouldn't. With data coming from an API it would be easier to see what all is returned when looking at the code six months down the line if the variables were explicitly called out. Its a matter of preference though.

Comment: Hi, I've placed an update on the topic, i cant get my code to work for some reason, please can i get you to take a look at it for me. Thank you for the help so far guys!